# Check count of files by country im filename

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are receiving 3 files into blob storage

Abc_metadata_GBR_20211118.csv

Abc_case_GBR_20211118.csv

Abc_control_GBR_20211118.csv

Abc_metadata_ARG_20211118.csv

I have to validate whether we received 3 files or not and 3 files should be of same country in azure data factory

GBR -- 3

ARG -- 1

Please help the way.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried using the below logic.

have as many get meta data activities as your country.

In my case, i am having two get meta data activities, one will look for file names that have the keyword 'file' and the other get meta data activity looks for the files that have the keyword 'py'

I am passing the regex in the file name part of the dataset that the get metadata activity uses.

Finally, i am taking the count and assigning to a variable.

Design:

[image: PipelineDesign]

Getmeta data properties:
[image: Getmetadata 1]
[image: Getmetadata 2]

Set Variable expression:

```
@string(length(activity('Get Metadata - search for py').output.childitems))
```

you can replace the wildcard with the country names.